# Do we have $(f^{-1}\widetilde{A^{(I)}})(D(g))\simeq ((f^{-1}\widetilde{A})(D(g)))^{(I)}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f:\operatorname{Spec}B\to \operatorname{Spec}A$ be a morphism of schemes. Given a set $I$, $\forall g\in B$, do we have $(f^{-1}\widetilde{A^{(I)}})(D(g))\simeq ((f^{-1}\widetilde{A})(D(g)))^{(I)}$?

Comment: At least, you should give the definition of $A^{(I)}$

Comment: @AnKhuongDoan  $A^{(I)}=\oplus_{i\in I}A$